# Modify Android's Manifest through config.xml in phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova

I am having a tough time trying to figure out how to add a custom permission to the Android Manifest using the phonegap config file.

I am using a [plugin](https://github.com/phearme/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin/) to read some data from a content provider. To read from this content provider I need to add a custom permission like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.READ" />
```

Adding it manually is not an option as I use a remote compile service.

I tried using the tag:

```
<gap:config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
     <uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.READ" />
</gap:config-file>
```

But no change is made in the manifest.

I have read a lot about this issue but it is not clear to me if I can add custom permission or only predefined ones.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Comment: if the plugin needs that permission, the plugin should add the permission on install, there is already an issue open for that https://github.com/phearme/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working! :)

This snippet works!

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="add">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.some.app.permission.READ" />
</gap:config-file>
```

**The key was that this tag only works when you use the phonegap build services, If you build it locally it will never take effect.** I lost a lot of time until I found a post pointing that. Anyway, all is good now.

Cheers!